# Matrix multiplication with CUDA: 2D blocks vs 1D blocks

Tags: matrix, cuda, parallel-processing

I'm currently working on a homework assignment where I have to implement several matrix multiplication kernels, try out several grid and block dimensions and benchmark the results.

My first kernels is using a 1D block of threads (where each thread block is responsible for computing one 1-by-n sub-matrix and each thread one element within this sub-matrix), my second one a 2D block (where each thread block is responsible for computing one square sub-matrix and each thread one element within this sub-matrix). Both of them are using the global memory.

I launched several tests with matrices of size 4096*4096 with threads per blocks ranging from 64 to 1024 for the 1D kernel, and from 8*8 to 32*32 for the 2D kernel. I expected to get the same performance for both kernels, but somehow the 2D kernel always seems to be marginally faster.

Could this be explained by the fact that with a 2D block of threads there is more memory access happening in the same "zone" and that this leverages some sort of caching mechanism ?

Comment: Yes, if you are using a cached memory access.

Answer (score 1):

Yes using 2D blocks reduces the number of different matrix elements accessed per block. This simple calculation should make it clear:

```
Calculation of A*B=C 
Matrix size: 4096*4096

Block size: 1024x1
Number of different elements read from Matrix A: 1 row = 4096 elements
Number of different elements read from Matrix B: 1024 columnes = 4096*1024
Sum: 4193280

Block size: 32x32
Number of different elements read from Matrix A: 32 rows = 32*1024
Number of different elements read from Matrix B: 32 columnes = 32*1024
Sum: 65536
```

To calculate C(i,j) in the resulting matrix you have to read the row i from matrix A and the column j from matrix B.

So if you want to calculate the first row of the result matrix you have to read N times the first row (assuming matrix is NxN) and each column once in matrix B.

```
4x1 Block

            v v v v
>0 1 2 3    0 1 2 3     x x x x
 4 5 6 7    4 5 6 7     - - - -
 8 9 A B    8 9 A B     - - - -
 C D E F    C D E F     - - - -

2x2 Block

            v v  
>0 1 2 3    0 1 2 3     x x - -
>4 5 6 7    4 5 6 7     x x - -
 8 9 A B    8 9 A B     - - - -
 C D E F    C D E F     - - - -
```

The arrows point to the rows and columns, that are needed to calculate the elemnts indicated by `x`.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain your "simple calculation" a little further?

Comment: @op, Note though, in your implementation as you've described it, you aren't directly reusing values. If you are using a cached method (default by fermi, using read-only cache, or enabling cahing in kepler), the benefit is that the probability of a value being in cache is higher since you are reusing values at a higher locality.